# Accessing attribute in $this->request

Tags: cakephp

I am a bloody CakePHP beginner starting with the latest CakePHP version 4.1.0.

I get the attribute for `identity` successfully with `$identity = $this->request->getAttribute('identity');`

Below the `print_()` dump for the `identity` object. And from here on I am stuck as I have no clue how to get the values `id`, `name`, `email`, ... inside the `data` object.

My intention is to get the current user properties. What did I understand wrong, how is the correct way to get the user data?

```
Authentication\Identity Object
(
    [config] => Array
        ( fieldMap] => Array ( [id] => id )    
        )
    [data] => App\Model\Entity\User Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Some Name
            [email] => name@example.com
            [password] => $2y$10$s******
            [role] => admin
            [created] => Cake\I18n\FrozenTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2020-07-27 15:23:59.000000
                    [timezone_type] => 3
                    [timezone] => UTC
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh oh, it's much simpler than thought.

`$identity->id|name|email` is the solution.

Comment: The non magic property access way would be to use the `get()` method, ie `$identity->get('id')`. https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/2/en/identity-object.html

Comment: Hi, could you help me please? How to get `$this->request->getAttribute('identity');` in to layout? I need some condition: if any user is logged in, add an element to default layout. I am reading CakePHP manual for 3 days now, I can not solve this